# One of Hermitian metric's properties?

Tags: metric-spaces, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

We now define a Hermitian manifold is a complex manifold in which unmixed components of metric tensor vanish $g_{ij}=g_{\bar{i}\bar{j}}=0$. Is this a propert of a Hermitian manifold? Or is it an extra imposed condition on the metric - this case Kaehler metric?

Comment: That's just linear algebra. It comes from viewing the manifold as a real manifold with a complex structure on its tangent space, and then trying to figure out which Riemannian metrics on the real manifold induce Hermitian (i.e., sesquilinear) ones. For example, if we would set $g_{i\bar j} = g_{\bar i \bar j} = 0$ and let the $g_{ij}$ be nonzero, we'd get a bilinear form $g(z,w)$ that's complex linear in both arguments, instead of complex linear in the first and complex antilinear in the second.

Comment: No, you can make that rigorous: just take an even-dimensional real vector space, put a complex structure on it, and work out which real inner products induce Hermitian ones on the complex space.

Comment: I don't have time to go into more detail, but I think you'll find everything you need in Chapter 1.2 of "Complex geometry" by Daniel Huybrechts.